# With TestNG+Spring, how to make @Bean configuration local to just one test?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, testng, integration-testing

I have added a `@Configuration` annotation and `@Bean` definition to one of my TestNG tests in order to override a deep `@Autowired` object with a mock.

Problem is, this has messed up all my other integration tests, where I need the real `@Autowired` object in place. How can I make the `@Bean` configuration local to just the one test where I want the mock?

I already tried the `@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)` annotation but that didn't work this time (although I've used it successfully in other cases).

Answer (score 0):

Add these two class-level annotations:

```
@ActiveProfiles({"this-test-name"})
@Profile("this-test-name")
```

Where `this-test-name` is the unique name of the specific test causing problems.